# Bind to child elements center in wpf canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

Making use of the itemsControl and canvas I'm binding to a observable collection and displaying visuals on the canvas. The displayed items use a datatemplate to control their visuals. The data template consists of a border and inside the border is an ellipse.

How can I bind to the center point of the ellipse in relation to the Canvas. Keeping in mind the ellipse is inside of border control?

The reason for binding directly to the center point of the ellipse rather than its parent border, is because there may be more than one ellipse inside a border. And the border itself can be moved inside the canvas by the user. Which would need to update the binding that it's child ellipse's positions have changed. So their values update.

Is your wanting to know why I want to bind to the center point of this ellipse, it is for data reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What is the control inside Border under which you are putting your Ellipses. Center of Ellipse makes sense only for certain Panels.

You can use some DP in your Ellipse getting affected when Position of your Border changes. Use a Binding for this using RelativeSource and apply a converter too.
This Converter would calculate the center.
Center of your Ellipse would depend upon its own position inside Border and Border position.

Comment: Inside border I have a grid. Which is where all these ellipse's exist. Could you provide and snippets?

Comment: You must be having DP corres. to Border's Canvas.Left/Top . You can bind DP corres. to Ellipse's center to Border DP. You need a converter to convert Border DP. Ellipse center = BorderDP(left) + Elpse margin + Elpse width÷2

Comment: By DP do you mean dependency property. What do you mean by corres?

Comment: DP: DependencyProperty, cores : Corresponding